# Read from INI file with duplicates

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have the following INI file:

```
    [Connection]
    Protocol=HTPP

    [Connection]
    Protocol=HTTPS
```

Is there some way I can save two protocols in two different variables? I tried to write:

```
    int a = GetPrivateProfileString(_T("Connection"), _T("Protocol"), _T(""), protocolChar, 32, path);
    int ab = GetPrivateProfileString(_T("Connection"), _T("Protocol"), _T(""), protocolChar2, 32, path);
```

And the result is that ProtocolChar, protocolChar2, though both receive the "HTTP".
How can I keep all the protocol in variable differently?

Comment: Not with `GetPrivateProfileString` et al, I'm pretty sure. You'd have to write your own INI file parser, if for some reason you can't avoid this duplication.

Comment: The only solution to this case is to build INI file parser of my own?

Comment: The only solution I could think of. If I knew of another one, I'd mention it, wouldn't I?

Comment: I would _not_ have this INI file. There's no strict standard but many implementations will not accept duplicated section names, let alone this double-duplication.

Answer (score 0):

No, `GetPrivateProfileString` does not support multiple sections with the same name and will always use the first one it encounters. There are a couple of straight forward approaches that can be used. The first is to simply append a number to the end of each section name.

```
[Connection0]
Protocol=HTPP

[Connection1]
Protocol=HTTPS

[Connection2]
Protocol=FTP

[Connection3]
Protocol=Telnet
```

With this approach you can iterate through the various `Connection` sections until you try loading one that does not exist.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    for (DWORD i = 0, size = 1; size != 0; ++i)
    {
        std::ostringstream name;

        name << "Connection" << i;
        std::string protocol(100, 0);
        size = GetPrivateProfileStringA(
            name.str().c_str(),
            "Protocol",
            NULL,
            &protocol[0],
            protocol.size(),
            "./test1.ini");

        if (size != 0)
        {
            protocol.resize(size);
            std::cout
                << name.str().c_str()
                << ":protocol=" << protocol << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Another way is to have a primary section (i.e. `Connections`) that defines a list of other sections each with a unique name. The benefit to this is that the sections are much easier to manage one one is deleted and eliminates the need to reorder the remaining sections. In this case you can simply rewrite the contents of `Connections`.

```
[Connections]
Connection0=HTTPConnection
Connection1=HTTPSConnection
Connection2=FTPConnection
Connection3=TelnetConnection

[HTTPConnection]
Protocol=HTPP

[HTTPSConnection]
Protocol=HTTPS

[FTPConnection]
Protocol=FTP

[TelnetConnection]
Protocol=Telnet
```

With this approach you iterate over the entries of `Connections` and then load each individual sections.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{

    for (DWORD i = 0, size = 1; size != 0; ++i)
    {
        std::ostringstream name;

        name << "Connection" << i;
        std::string section(100, 0);
        size = GetPrivateProfileStringA(
            "Connections",
            name.str().c_str(),
            NULL,
            &section[0],
            section.size(),
            "./test1.ini");

        if (size != 0)
        {
            section.resize(size);
            std::string protocol(100, 0);
            size = GetPrivateProfileStringA(
                section.c_str(),
                "Protocol",
                NULL,
                &protocol[0],
                protocol.size(),
                "./test1.ini");
            if (size != 0)
            {
                protocol.resize(size);
                std::cout
                    << name.str().c_str()
                    << ":"
                    << section
                    << ":protocol=" << protocol << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```